# ActionBar Mic Button(Voice Search) in SearchView

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I am implementing `Action Bar`. I want 2 buttons in Search field area of `Action Bar SearchView` like Flipkart app.

[image: Flipkart app have two buttons in SearchView]

Like above screenshot, I want 2 buttons, first one is for Voice Search and another is for Barcode Scanner, when Search icon clicked and `SearchView` of `Actionbar` appears. I am able to implement `actionbar serahcview` with search icon. But I am bit confused why voice search not appearing in my app. Have a look on my source code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

        setSearchTextColour(searchView);
        setCloseSearchIcon(searchView);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void setSearchTextColour(SearchView searchView) {
        int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        EditText searchPlate = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);
        searchPlate.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.novoda_blue));
//        searchPlate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_holo_light);
        searchPlate.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
    } 

 private void setCloseSearchIcon(SearchView searchView) {
        try {
            Field searchField = SearchView.class.getDeclaredField("mCloseButton");
            searchField.setAccessible(true);
            ImageView closeBtn = (ImageView) searchField.get(searchView);
            closeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.action_cancel);

            searchField = SearchView.class.getDeclaredField("mVoiceButton");
            searchField.setAccessible(true);
            ImageView voiceBtn = (ImageView) searchField.get(searchView);
            voiceBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("SearchView", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("SearchView", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

**Screenshot of What I got from above code :**

[image: Output of Above Code]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 24):

First, you should read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)

AndroidManifest.xml for your activity with searchview widget (singleTop is necessary, please read the link above):

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity" 
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" 
    android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Create *.../res/xml/**searchable.xml*** with this:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"/>
```

Modify onCreateOptionsMenu (last two lines are matter)

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_action_bar_menu, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.hint));

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
}
```

And finally override **onNewIntent()**:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        doSearch(query);
    }
}
```

After these changes you will see a mic button in a searchview.

Comment: I want to effect on current Activity, Dont want to open New Intent. Is there any posibility.

Comment: Why not? You can save an activity state using bundles.

Comment: "After these changes you will see a mic button in a searchview." Only if the device supports it.

Comment: How is posible show voice icon in other activity? only appear mainactivity

Comment: @Webserveis define meta-data for that activity like it is for MainActivity in my example.

Comment: Will this work if my Searchview is not in the toolbar? The mic button is not showing.

Answer (score 1):

Please check in your code if you didn't call:

```
 searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true)
```

By removing it you should see the 'voice' icon.

Answer (score 0):

just put the `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in your Manifest's activity tag

```
<activity android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            >
          ....
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"></action>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".Activity.MainActivity"
                ></meta-data>

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable">

            </meta-data>

        </activity>
```