# How to add mic button in searchview of actionbar

Tags: android, searchview

I want to add mic in searchview of actionbar.

I tried this [ActionBar Mic Button(Voice Search) in SearchView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370655/actionbar-mic-buttonvoice-search-in-searchview). but mic is not showing in searchview

Please help

Answer (score 0):

here is the link to add voice Search. [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#VoiceSearch)

Comment: i tried same solution .. mic is coming on keyboard not in actionBar

Comment: i have tried this tutorial and icon is displaying [link](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-adding-search-to-your-apps/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines in your searchable.

```
android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
```

and put the `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in your Manifest's activity tag.

```
<activity android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            >
          ....
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"></action>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".Activity.MainActivity"
                ></meta-data>

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable">

            </meta-data>

        </activity>
```